# Remove all lines after /

Tags: script, notepad++, regex

I have 2 lists one with this format:

```
http://www.example.com/archives/573
http://www.example.com/1812.html
http://example.com/hello-world/
```

but i want it in this format

```
www.example.com
www.example.com
example.com
```

And another list in this format:

```
4|345|example.com|themes/vip|Automattic|Nginx
5|425|example.com|themes/informer|Softlayer|Nginx
6|502|example.com|themes/ljq|Media Temple|Apache
```

...

but i need it in the same format

```
example.com
example.com
example.com
```

...

How do I do this?

Comment: For your first problem, use as *Find what* `^.*?://(.*?)/.*$`  and replace with `\1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Case 1

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `http://(.*?)/(.*)`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
http://www.example.com/archives/573
http://www.example.com/1812.html
http://example.com/hello-world/
```

**After**:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com
example.com
```

---

#### Case 2

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*)`
- Set "Replace with" to `\3`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
4|345|example.com|themes/vip|Automattic|Nginx
5|425|example.com|themes/informer|Softlayer|Nginx
6|502|example.com|themes/ljq|Media Temple|Apache
```

**After**:

```
example.com
example.com
example.com
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)